# Graphs (line chart, pie chart) in web application with mapreduce programming

Tags: web-applications, hadoop, mapreduce, webhdfs

hello friends i am developing a web application where i need to write a map reduce code for processing a data from Hadoop Distributed file system and draw various graphs on the basis of reducer output so i am developing the application in Java in eclipse so how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to try using hive. create on ehive table which contains the output of your reducer file. Using JDBC or ODBC connectivity pull the data from hive to your front end and consume for your graphical representation like pie charts.